# Shortcut for axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

ggplot labels are typically added by the augument xlab/ylab, e.g.

```
 ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()+ xlab('x_label')+ ylab('y_label')
```

Is there any shortcut to predefine the label and call them? e.g.: **mylabels** is  predefined . This would make repetitive use of certain labels more efficient.

```
mylabels <- xlab('x_label')+ylab('y_label') 
ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + mylabels
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store the label information in a list as follows

```
mylabels <- list(
  xlab("x_label"), 
  ylab("y_label")
)
ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + mylabels
```